# How can I init and use i18next plugin in website project?

Tags: javascript, npm, i18next

After reading the document of i18next, I am still confused about how to init & use it in both navigator auto detecting way and event trigger way.
Do I need to include it with `<script>` tag again if I have had npm install it?
Totally novice in npm, thanks for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use libraries installed with NPM in the browser, you traditionally need to use a build tool like Browserify or Webpack. Asking how to use an npm library in the browser is too broad of a question for StackOverflow.

If you aren't familiar with those tools and want to get up and running quickly, you can just include [browser ready Javacript file](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/i18next.min.js) in a script tag. Hit the "Raw" button, download the file, then include the downloaded file in your project like any other script file.

Comment: thanks for help, still want to know about how to auto detect navigator language via i18next. To implementing this function, what kind of init process should I do, thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good medium for asking broad, back-and-forth style questions. If this answered your original question of how to use i18next in a website, click the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as correct. Otherwise please refine the question to be specific, and show the code you're trying that isn't working.